# setTimeout atrelado a um onload não funciona

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma página em PHP que confirma ou não o envio do e-mail do usuário pela página de contato. Quero que depois de 10 segundos (tempo suficiente para que o aviso de confirmação seja lido), o `window.location` seja a página inicial do site. Estou tentando da seguinte forma:

```
window.onload = function(){
  setTimeout(window.location = "http://homedosite.com.br", 10000);
}
```

O problema é que quando aparece a página de confirmação, simplesmente o `window.location` é setado sem aguardar os 10 segundos. O que pode estar acontecendo?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

O problema é que como você colocou diretamente `window.location = ...` dentro da chamada de `setTimeout`, o Javascript irá tentar avaliar o conteúdo dentro dos parênteses imediatamente, e por isso a página já é redirecionada.

Experimente trocar para:

```js
window.onload = function(){
    setTimeout(function () { window.location = "http://homedosite.com.br"; }, 10000);
}
```

Comment: Agoora funcionou!

Answer (score 9):

Ao executar este código, o JavaScript primeiro executa o `window.location = "blablabla"` e pega o valor de retorno (no caso, `"http://homedosite.com.br"` e então o envia para o `setTimeout`, ou seja, ele é executado antes da chamada do `setTimeout`. Para fazer o que você quer, use o seguinte código:

```
window.onload = function(){
  setTimeout(function () {
    window.location = "http://homedosite.com.br";
  }, 10000);
}
```

Ao fazer isso, você estará enviando uma função como parâmetro para o `setTimeout`, função esta que será executada após os 10 segundos.

Dá uma lida nesse [artigo da MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout).

Comment: Também funcionou... :-D
Obrigado por ter respondido!